# I forgot to take my first Gravity reading

Tags: first-time-brewer, mead, gravity-reading

I am making my first batch of mead ima first time brewer and I forgot to take my first gravity reading what should I do?

Answer (score 6):

It isn't too much of a big deal. If you have the nutritional information from the honey you can calculate how much of it was pure sugar (mainly glucose in honey I believe). Then it is a simple case of using an online calculator to to calculate an estimated SG for your recipe. If precision means slightly less you could simply use the preloaded 'honey' option in many online recipe creators to calculate an estimated SG based on typical sugar volume (such as https://brewgr.com/homebrew-recipe-calculator).

For example

- 20L batch
- 5KG of honey

Nutritional info of the honey I have in my cupboard is 80.8 grams of sugar per 100g of honey. Thus 80.8*50 = 4,040g of sugar in 5KG of honey. Thus put 4.04kg of simple sugar or 5kg of honey into a calculator gives an estimated SG of between 1.073 and 1.077 depending on which you use.

Depending which one you go with it will of course slightly alter your abv calculations but I would argue it is better than not knowing at all.